# Apply a vector-returning function to a data.frame grouping by several factors

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

Here is a sample of my data frame

```
charact_fraction    pure_charact    sample  replicate   identity
0.08348135  clean   An006   1   70
0.078947368 clean   An006   1   70
0.090277778 clean   An006   1   70
0.044399596 clean   An006   2   70
0   clean   An006   2   70
0.049348869 clean   An006   2   70
0.218818381 mixed   An011   1   70
0.112068966 mixed   An011   1   70
1   pure    An011   1   70
0   clean   An011   2   70
0.214285714 mixed   An011   2   70
0.2180937   mixed   An011   2   70
```

I want to bin `charact_fraction` and calculate bin frequencies grouped by several factors. The resulting data frame is supposed to look like this

```
bin_frequency   bin sample  replicate   identity
…   0-0.1   An006   1   70
…   …   …   …   …
…   0.9-1.0 An006   1   70
…   0-0.1   An011   1   70
…   …   …   …   …
…   0.9-1.0 An011   1   70
…   …   …   …   …
```

I've got the function to return bin frequencies.

```
get_freqs <- function(dat_vector, breaks) {
    hist(dat_vector, breaks=breaks, include.lowest=TRUE, plot=FALSE)$counts
}
```

And I can generate the bins.

```
breaks=seq(0,1,by=0.1)
bins = paste(breaks, breaks[-1], sep="-")
bins = bins[-length(ranges)]
```

I believe this is my closest shot so far, but it's obviously far from the desired output:

```
with(df, tapply(charact_part, list(sample, replicate, identity), get_freqs, breaks=breaks))
```

I've got extremely ugly Python code that does the thing, but I want to have something cleaner and functional in R. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd guess you are looking for `cut` though I'm  not sure regarding your desired output really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `cut()` and `ddply()` from 'plyr' should give you a data frame with frequencies for the various subsets of your factors of interest. So something like:

```
library(plyr)
df$bin <- cut(df$charact_fraction, seq(0, 1, 0.1), include.lowest=TRUE)
df$obs <- 1  # Makes counting easy in next step
xtabs <- ddply(df, .(bin, sample, replicate, identity), summarise,
    frequency = sum(obs))
```

One potential downside to using ddply here is that the resulting data frame will not include subsets with zero observations. If that's a problem, you could create a complete matrix, merge in the observed frequencies, and then replace the NAs with 0s like this:

```
xtabs.grid <- with(df, expand.grid(bin = unique(bins), sample = unique(sample),
  replicate = unique(replicate), identity = unique(identity)))
xtabs.full <- merge(xtabs.grid, xtabs, all.x = TRUE)
xtabs.full[is.na(xtabs.full)] <- 0
```

Note that, for the merge to work smoothly, the variable names given to `expand.grid()` need to match the ones produced by `ddply()` in the preceding step.

Addendum: Here is a version that uses 'dplyr' functions and piping to do all of this in one shot:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(bin = cut(charact_fraction, seq(0, 1, 0.1), include.lowest=TRUE)) %>%
  count(bin, sample, replicate, identity) %>%
  left_join(with(df, expand.grid(bin=levels(cut(charact_fraction, seq(0, 1, 0.1), include.lowest=TRUE)), sample=unique(sample), replicate=unique(replicate), identity=unique(identity))), .) %>%
  mutate(n = ifelse(is.na(n)==FALSE, n, 0))
```

Comment: A hell lot of cool stuff you've got there in your answer. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`cut` may be the way to go:

```
x <- gsub("\\[|\\]|\\(", "", cut(df$charact_fraction, seq(0,1, .1), include.lowest=T))
df$range <- gsub(",", "-", x)
df
#    charact_fraction pure_charact sample replicate identity   range
# 1        0.08348135        clean  An006         1       70   0-0.1
# 2        0.07894737        clean  An006         1       70   0-0.1
# 3        0.09027778        clean  An006         1       70   0-0.1
# 4        0.04439960        clean  An006         2       70   0-0.1
# 5        0.00000000        clean  An006         2       70   0-0.1
# 6        0.04934887        clean  An006         2       70   0-0.1
# 7        0.21881838        mixed  An011         1       70 0.2-0.3
# 8        0.11206897        mixed  An011         1       70 0.1-0.2
# 9        1.00000000         pure  An011         1       70   0.9-1
# 10       0.00000000        clean  An011         2       70   0-0.1
# 11       0.21428571        mixed  An011         2       70 0.2-0.3
# 12       0.21809370        mixed  An011         2       70 0.2-0.3
```

If you would also like the count, you can add:

```
lst <- lapply(split(df, df$sample), function(x) {
  within(x, count <- table(range)[match(range, names(table(range)))])
}) 
`rownames<-`(do.call(rbind, lst), NULL)
#    charact_fraction pure_charact sample replicate identity   range count
# 1        0.08348135        clean  An006         1       70   0-0.1     6
# 2        0.07894737        clean  An006         1       70   0-0.1     6
# 3        0.09027778        clean  An006         1       70   0-0.1     6
# 4        0.04439960        clean  An006         2       70   0-0.1     6
# 5        0.00000000        clean  An006         2       70   0-0.1     6
# 6        0.04934887        clean  An006         2       70   0-0.1     6
# 7        0.21881838        mixed  An011         1       70 0.2-0.3     3
# 8        0.11206897        mixed  An011         1       70 0.1-0.2     1
# 9        1.00000000         pure  An011         1       70   0.9-1     1
# 10       0.00000000        clean  An011         2       70   0-0.1     1
# 11       0.21428571        mixed  An011         2       70 0.2-0.3     3
# 12       0.21809370        mixed  An011         2       70 0.2-0.3     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `table`:

```
with( dfrm, table( cut( charact_function, breaks=10, include.lowest=TRUE),
       sample, replicate, identity) )
```

You could also use `breaks=breaks`, but I just wanted to demonstrate a different use of that parameter  ... slightly more compact.

This is a 4 way classification, although it's possible you wanted three two-way classifications in which case it's:

```
cat_char_func <- cut( charact_function, breaks=10, include.lowest=TRUE)
sapply( dfrm[ , c('sample', 'replicate', 'identity')], 
                    function(cat) { table( cat_char_func, cat) }
        )
```

Comment: I don't see how I can transform this into a `data.frame` as shown in my question.